# Why does isalpha() stop at spaces?

Tags: c++, arrays, char

```
int main(){
char check[256], c;
int ch=0;
cin >> check;
while (check[ch]){
    c = check[ch];
    if (isalpha(c))putchar(c);
    ch++;
}
}
```

If for example `check[256]` is   "this and this"   the program will only print  "this"  what means that at the first space it stops , first question is why , and second is there a way to stop it so it will print either   "this and this" or   "thisandthis" ?

Comment: Please read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). My guess is that your input routine is not doing what you think it does.

Comment: There *are* mistakes. And the longer you wait to find them, the longer your program will produce garbage. Post the shortest code neccessary to reproduce your problem. Note: the shortest code should *compile* when I paste it into a compiler!. That means there should be a `main`.

Comment: In short: Try to write a program that **only** reads an entire line of user input.

Comment: cin >> string_variable is formatted input ignoring leading and stopping at white spaces

Comment: is there a way to make cin >> string_variable not stop at spaces , or any other function that will work ?

Comment: @Lendrit: look at `std::getline()`

Comment: `std::getline()` is used for `string` not for `char`.

Comment: `isalpha` does not "stop" because it does not _move_ in the first place. Apply basic logic to problem-solving!!

Answer (score 4):

If you had built a short example, like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main()
{
    char check[256] = "this and this"; 

    int ch = 0;

    while (check[ch]) 
    {
        char c = check[ch];
        if (isalpha(c)) putchar(c);
        ch++;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

You would have noticed this works exactly as you want it to work. So the culprit is this line:

```
cin >> check;
```

If you want to read a line, use getline:

```
std::getline(std::cin, check);
```

You should really be using

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
```

and stop using char arrays. You are using C++, not C.

Answer (score 2):

In this line:

```
cin >> check;
```

only the first word will be read into the char array, because this is the default behavior of cin. Please verify that the array contains the entire string.

Answer (score 0):

I'm surprised that no one has objected this yet. By all means not use a plain `char` array with `std::cin`. Have you considered what might happen if some user would enter a word longer than whatever your buffersize may be?

Of course, you would use `std::string` instead, and, of course, you would use `std::getline(std::cin, s)` to read a line.

Example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cctype>

int main() {
    std::string s;
    if (std::getline(std::cin, s))
        for (char c : s)
            if (std::isalpha(c))
                std::cout << c;
    std::cout << "\n";
}
```

Output:

```
$ g++ test.cc -std=c++11 && echo "Hello World" | ./a.out
HelloWorld
```